# g++ have trouble selecting the right method

Tags: c++

I am puzzled why compiler (g++ ver 4.8.4) have trouble compiling the following code snippet. In the call `x.addField("hi", s.size());`, I thought compiler could simply use the method `void addField(const char *fieldName, long value)` because it's obviously the best match.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class strDum {
public:
    void addField(const char *fieldName, const char *fmt, ...);
    void addField(const char *fieldName, bool value);
    void addField(const char *fieldName, long value);
    void addField(const char *fieldName, double value);
};

void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, const char *fmt, ...) {
}
void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, bool value) {
}
void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, long value) {
}
void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, double value) {
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    string s = "hello";
    strDum x;
    x.addField("hi", s.size());
    return 0;
}
```

Here is compiler error message

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 te4.cc
te4.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
te4.cc:29:27: error: call of overloaded ‘addField(const char [3], std::basic_string<char>::size_type)’ is ambiguous
  x.addField("hi", s.size());
                           ^
te4.cc:29:27: note: candidates are:
te4.cc:16:6: note: void strDum::addField(const char*, const char*, ...) <near match>
 void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, const char *fmt, ...) {
      ^
te4.cc:16:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::basic_string<char>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const char*’
te4.cc:18:6: note: void strDum::addField(const char*, bool)
 void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, bool value) {
      ^
te4.cc:20:6: note: void strDum::addField(const char*, long int)
 void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, long value) {
      ^
te4.cc:22:6: note: void strDum::addField(const char*, double)
 void strDum::addField(const char *fieldName, double value) {
      ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually that would have the signature `(const char *, std::size_t)`

Comment: Thanks @corykramer, it works. I wonder why can't compiler change `long` to `std::size_t` automatically.

Comment: It *can* change to those types, but as @Barry mentions below, none of them is *better* than the other, so the function is ambiguous.

Comment: Wish g++ will allow user to add a configuration on type conversion preference:  for types int, const int, unsigned int etc  convert them to long if possible. for float or unsigned float, convert them to double first if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments in this call:

```
x.addField("hi", s.size());
```

have type `{const char[3], size_t}`. We have three viable overload candidates for this set of arguments:

```
void addField(const char*, bool );
void addField(const char*, long );
void addField(const char*, double );
```

In each case, `size_t` can be converted to the second argument type via an Integral Conversion (`size_t` to `bool` or `size_t` to `long`) or a Floating-integral conversion (`size_t` to `double`). None of these conversions is any better than the other - they all have the same rank: Conversion. Hence, there is no *best* viable candidate because we cannot distinguish between the three options.

One source of confusion may be that `long` is "closer" to `size_t` than `bool` is. But this doesn't matter from the perspective of conversion ranking. They both involve a integral conversion and there's no differentiation<sup>1</sup> between the different integral conversion types.

To disambiguate, either:

- provide a new overload: `addField(const char*, size_t)`
- cast the second argument to be the type you want - `x.addField("hi", static_cast<long>(s.size()))`
- collapse all the overloads into a function template: `template <class T> void addField(const char*, T)`

Probably you'll want the last one.

---

<sup>1</sup>There *is* a differentiation between an integral *promotion* (e.g. `char` to `int`) and an integral *conversion* though (e.g. `int` to `char`). The promotion is a better conversion than the conversion.

Comment: Thanks @Barry.  I added a method `void addField(const char *fieldName, std::size_t value);` and that took care of the compile error with `s.size()`, however, it gave similar errors when I try to do:  `x.addField("hi", 123);`.   I know `static_cast<long>` may help, but it will make the main function look ugly.  Wonder if there is a elegant approach?

Comment: @codingFun Same problem - ambiguous conversion. You should probably make `addField` a function template.

Comment: Thanks @barry for the good suggestion.  I added a separate function for int and for std::size_t in the original code snippet and it worked.